# Periodic distribution of a piecewise continous function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Let $f$  be a  periodic piecewise continous function with period $2\pi$, and  its derivative (classical derivative) is also a piecewise continous function and we denote by  $\frac{df}{dx}$. Let $x_{1},..,x_{n}$ discontinuity points of $f$ in $(-\pi,\pi]$.Then its distributional derivative $f'$ is given by
$$f'=\frac{df}{dx}+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}[f(x_{j}^{+})-f(x_{j}^{-})]\delta_{x_{j}}.$$
$f(x_{j}^{+})=\lim_{x \downarrow x_{j}} f(x),f(x_{j}^{-})=\lim_{x \uparrow x_{j}} f(x) $ and $\delta_{x_{j}} $ is the dirac function centered at $x_{j}\in \mathbb{R}$
Note that $f$ defines a periodic distribution by the formula
$$\langle f,\varphi\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\varphi(x)dx$$
Well, Can you help me understand what $\frac{df}{dx}$ means in the distributional derivative?
and How to pove that the distributional derivative has that form?

Comment: df/dx is just the classical derivative on all the points where the function is smooth. To prove your formula, just use the definition of distributional derivative. Where do you have a difficulty ?

Comment: Yes, but in the distributional derivative have other meaning.

Comment: Yes, so here, $f'$ is your distributional derivative, and $\mathrm df/\mathrm dx$ is your classical derivative, defined at all points except at points where the function has a jump. Example, if $f = (1+x^2)\, \mathrm{sgn}(x)$, then $\mathrm df/\mathrm dx = 2\, |x|$ (except at $x=0$) while $f' = 2\, |x| + 2 \,\delta_0$